# writing a c++ script for using GDB commands and GDB results (like variable values) while running another c++ program

Tags: python, c++, debugging, gdb, gdb-python

I need a c++ script to automate GDB debugging another c++ program. the c++ script has to be able to run gdb commands and get the results from it and use it inside the script to save variable values for later usage, my main questions are:

1. is there a c++ library for using GDB programmatically (running gdb commands like

> continue

> step into

) and getting value variables

2. if there is no library, how can I implement the c++ script myself?
3. can I use a python script instead of a c++ script to debug the c++ program?
4. if it is possible to use python, what libraries can I use for using GDB programmatically in python?
5. giving an implementation example for scripts would be a good guideline and help

thanks

Comment: You can build gdb with [Python support](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Python.html#Python) (or you might already have it).

Comment: BTW: I found that out by entering "gdb python" in a search engine.

Comment: gdb usually comes with Python support enabled by default.